# Python Multithreading web pages with ajax

Tags: python, ajax, multithreading, pyqt4

Well  I am troubling couple of days to solve next problem.. Unfortunately there is not so much examples of this so i am asking you.

Problem: Multithreading (parallel) web pages (`ajax`), i currently use `phantomjs` but it is very slow specially for scraping pages which have multiple ajax calls, so i saw this `pyqt4` code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys

class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        self.index=1
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.page().loadFinished.connect(self.print_load_finished)


    def print_load_finished(self):    #I want code generated of second ajax call!!
        if self.index==0:
            frame = self.page().mainFrame()
            #print (frame.toHtml())
            self.close()
        else:
            self.index=0

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    br = Browser()
    url = QUrl('http://www.some_url.com')
    br.load(url1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And other for multithreading, but with `urllib.request`:

```
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread):

    data_downloaded = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, url):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        info = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url).info()
        self.data_downloaded.emit('%s\n%s' % (self.url, info))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_download)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def start_download(self):
        urls = ['http://www.some_url.com','http://www.some_url.com','http://www.some_url.com']
        self.threads = []
        for url in urls:
            downloader = DownloadThread(url)
            downloader.data_downloaded.connect(self.on_data_ready)
            self.threads.append(downloader)
            downloader.start()

    def on_data_ready(self, data):
        print (data)
        self.list_widget.addItem((data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can any one tell me how to combine these two togheter so i am able to scrape more pages (`ajax`) at ones? Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? Does anyone have any suggestion, please?!